# How to close menu after using ToolStripTextBox

Tags: vb.net

In my application I try to use ToolStripTextBox under menu.
My desired usage is to write a number in it and when I press ENTER key that some code executes and menu closes.
But my menu remains opened.

How to close it by code?

```
Private Sub ToolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ToolStripTextBox1.KeyDown
     If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If Val(ToolStripTextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
            Dim strsif As String = ToolStripTextBox1.Text
            For ptr As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                If DataGridView1.Item(0, ptr).Value.ToString() = strsif Then
                    SelectRowInDataGridview(Cint(strsif))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

    'CLOSE MENU HERE

    End If
End Sub
```

WinForms, .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `TextBox1` is inside one of the containers of a `ToolStrip` allowing to include a `TextBox` (i.e., `SplitButton` or `DropDownButton`); and that you want to "contract"/stop-showing this container once the condition is met (a number is input and the "Enter" key is pressed). You can get that by writing the following code under `'CLOSE MENU HERE`:

```
Container.HideDropDown()
```

Where `Container` is the name of the `SplitButton`/`DropDownButton`, by default: `ToolStripSplitButton1`/`ToolStripDropDownButton1`.

Comment: Hello varocarbas and thank you for advice, it work almost as expected. By pressing ENTER I have to HideDropDown on my ListaToolStripMenuItem. But here is an issue if I fire a menu with ALT key then go to item "Lista" and then by key down goto my ToolStripTextBox1 and press ENTER to confirm input THEN dropdown closes but menuitem Lista remain selected (remain blue square arround it). Can this be solved too?

Comment: @user973238 this sounds as a completely different problem (and you know the rules: you cannot keep asking over and over in the same question :)). In any case, from what I understand, this has nothing to do with showing/hiding the dropdown (what is managed by the given container, as said above), but with the specific element (textBox in this case) and the .Select() method. You cannot "unselect" an item but can just select another one, by simply doing, otheritem.Select(). In any case the ToolStrip is a pretty problematic control (and in a so old .NET as 2.0, most likely, even more) (...)

Comment: @user973238 (...) you should take the theory (for example the aforementioned HideDropDown()) with lots of caution and perform an intensive validation every time to make sure that your code delivers exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my question is clear enough. We talk about menu strip, not a ToolStrip if that is different, I am not so deep in NET. Your code do exact what you tell him to do, it HIDES dropdown but still leaves parent Menu "activated". Since my ToolStripTextBox1 is child of ListaToolStripMenuItem and which is child of MenuStrip1 this is same thema and same question. Maybe I have to ask "How to completely close a menu after using of ToolStripTextBox1 by code"?

Comment: @user973238 ToolStrip and MenuStrip are different controls (although behave quite similarly; I did answer for a ToolStrip and my answer worked fine with your MenuStrip), perhaps you should make this point clearer in your question. Regarding what you are saying I think that I do understood it: the dropdown is hidden what I understood that was your question ("how to close..."). Now you are talking about "being highlighted/selected" which is a different thing, but I have answered it anyway... will explain it again (out of space)

Comment: @user973238 When the given form/program is used, one of its controls HAS TO be selected/highlighted. You CANNOT UNSELECT a given control (because it might drive to situations where no control is selected what, as said, cannot happen), but you CAN SELECT any other control. If, after closing the dropdown, it is selected and you don't want it to be selected, you have to select another control, for example the whole menuStrip (MenuStripName.Select()). As you can see, this is a general behaviour for all the controls, something different than the specific HideDropDown behaviour.

Comment: OK, with adding DataGridView1.Select() is something better (no more square around any item). But Menu which contain my textBox is still activated what can be seen if you drag over any his item by mouse.

Comment: @user973238 ToolStrip/MenuStrip is a pretty problematic control. What I told you is the general rule working for any control, but it might have "some peculiarities" (some times, things which you can only know/fix after testing). In this case, this is provoked most likely by the fact that the given item is a sub-control within the main MenuStrip and thus it can remained selected. That's why I proposed you to select the whole menuStrip it might do the trick. Also you can play around with .Focus(). But, as said, this is a pretty problematic control and this question is outside your question.

Comment: @user973238 PS: what is clear is that "this selection" is something internal of the menuStrip and thus if the menuStrip control is not selected, the user cannot do anything (the focus is on the other other control you selected, DataGridView1). Please, correct your question to explain properly what you meant and to highlight that this is a MenuStrip. I think that I have done more than enough.

Comment: OK varocarbas, I will try to improve but as is even now is usable. Also I try this with popup menu where .Hide work as expected. OK, thanks for a workable solution.